# How to display react-redux state value without using setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This kind of problem has been answered before but I could not find a general way which works for all. Here is the state value screenshot:
[image]

The value came from node.js as

```
return res.send(available_balance);
```

Action was set as:

```
type: FETCH_DIGITAL_WALLET_BALANCE_BY_ID_SUCCESS,
digitalWalletUserAccountBalanceById: balance
```

As you can see the redux store has set the data right no doubt.

Now when I show the data as:

```
class UserUpdateModal extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    ...
   }
   render() {
          return ( 
             <div> 
              <h1>{this.props.initialValues.wallet_balance_by_id}</h1>
             </div>
          )
   }
}
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return{
     initialValues: {
            wallet_balance_by_id: state.digitalWalletUserAccountBalanceById.data,
     }
  }
}
export default connect(
mapStateToProps,
)(withRouter(UserUpdateModal));
```

I get Error:

[image]

But when I create :

```
class UserUpdateModal extends React.Component{
this.state = {
    wallet_balance_by_id:'',
}
this.getWallet_balance_by_id = this.getWallet_balance_by_id.bind(this);
}

 getWallet_balance_by_id(){
    this.state.viewWalletBalance==false? 
    this.setState({viewWalletBalance:true}):this.setState({viewWalletBalance:false})
  }

....
```

}

Then call the function as input button it set the state and shows to the screen. So what is the basic way to shoe the redux state value to the screen without using a button to come around from the problem.

```
<h2>Balance</h2>
                                
     <h1>{ this.state.viewWalletBalance ? 
     this.props.initialValues.wallet_balance_by_id : null }</h1>
     <input type="submit" value="Balance" onClick={this.getWallet_balance_by_id} />
     {/* <h1>{this.props.initialValues.wallet_balance_by_id}</h1> */}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see the redux store has set the data right no doubt.

The redux store gets the right value *eventually* but it doesn't *always* have the right value.  Look again at the screenshot that you posted of Redux Dev Tools.  *Eventually* the value is a `number` `10.12`.  But *initially* the value is an empty `object` `{}`.  Why?

The problem is not in your component code or any of the code that you have included here.  The problem is the initial state of your Redux store, which is setting the `state.digitalWalletUserAccountBalanceById.data` property to an empty object `{}`.  Fix the initial state and your problems will go away.  It should be a `number` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, ( and `mapStateToProps` ) it seems like the initial value of `wallet_balance_by_id` is an `Object` ( which is `state.digitalWalletUserAccountBalanceById.data` ) which will throw that error because you can't render the `Object` like that, this is happening before the state update

> <strike>{}</strike> => 10.12

It works when you click on the button because the value changes to a number and you can legally render it

update `mapStateToProps` to :

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return{
     initialValues: {
            wallet_balance_by_id: state.digitalWalletUserAccountBalanceById.data.wallet_balance_by_id,
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//      this should not be an object
           
     }
  }
}
```

Or better :

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return{
     initialValues: state.digitalWalletUserAccountBalanceById.data
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried as :function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return{
    digitalWalletUserAccountBalanceById: state.digitalWalletUserAccountBalanceById.data,
  }
}------THEN <h1>{this.props.digitalWalletUserAccountBalanceById}</h1> same red error comes

Comment: If  I use <h1>{this.props.digitalWalletUserAccountBalanceById.toString()}</h1> It works but for fraction of time it shows up [object Object] on screen then shows the number